# Contents lost from webview

Tags: android, xml

I am using two layout.In first layout I made story design like data,Title,images etc and then include first layout in second layout.In second layout I have admob and related story list.when I opening this page showing all contents but when click ads or other functionality and after comeback same page then webview data is lost.

This problem happening in some devices like Xperia z,Moto X but In samsung and Xiomi this thing working fine.

How to solve this problem.here is the XML code.

```
    <LinearLayout 

             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:background="@color/white"
             android:orientation="vertical">

         <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/contentDetailImageLayout"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="220dp" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannerImagecondetail_slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/default_logo_list" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_title_slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red_header"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/charcha_main"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/increaseImage_slider"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/text_increament" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/updated_date_slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/increaseImage_slider"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="March 16,2015 10:55 IST"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/updated_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/updated_date_slider"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="@string/ID_STRING_UPDATED"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/updated_logo"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/updated_title"
            android:src="@drawable/clock" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storyTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/heading_font_size" />

   <WebView
        android:id="@+id/storyText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/ads_webview_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:background="@color/white"
             android:visibility="gone" />
             <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="7.2">

             com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
              android:id="@+id/adView"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              ads:adSize="BANNER"
              ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
         </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>  


 This is the java code



    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder = null;

       inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_detail_sliding_row, container, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();



    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    viewHolder.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
    viewHolder.storyText = (WebView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.storyText);
    viewHolder.imgflag = (ImageView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.bannerImagecondetail_slider);
    viewHolder.updatedDate = (TextView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.updated_date_slider);
    viewHolder.cat_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title_slider);
    viewHolder.increaseText = (ImageView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.increaseImage_slider);

    /*if(position == list.size()-1){
        mRightArraw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        mRightArraw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }*/

    String f_title = list.get(position).getGalleryTitle();
    String imageurl = list.get(position).getGalleryImage();
    String time = list.get(position).getGalleryTime();
    String f_story_text = list.get(position).getGalleryBody();

    Controller.getInstance().Eventtracker("PhotoGallery swipe" ,"slide", f_title );
    // set to the TextViews
    if(f_title != null){
        try
        {
            f_title = new String(f_title.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
        }

        viewHolder.title .setText(f_title);
    }

    WebSettings webSettings = viewHolder.storyText.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (f_story_text != null){
        f_story_text = f_story_text.replaceAll("<b>", "");
        Spannable sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(f_story_text));
        Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
        final String html = "<body>" + Html.toHtml(sp) + "</body>";
        viewHolder.storyText.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
        viewHolder.storyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        if (time != null)
            date = form.parse(time);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // set the time in ago formate.
    long timeInMilliseconds = date.getTime();
    String mFtime = Utility.calculateRelativeTime(timeInMilliseconds);
    /*if(mFtime.contains("in ")){
        mFtime = mFtime.replace("in", "from");

    }*/


    long currentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(timeInMilliseconds > currentTime){
        viewHolder.updatedDate.setText("0 min ago");
    }
    else{


     if(mFtime.contains("minut")){
        mFtime = mFtime.replace("minutes", "min");
        if(mFtime.contains("minute")){
            mFtime = mFtime.replace("minute", "min");
        }
    }
    if(mFtime.contains("hour")){
        mFtime = mFtime.replace("hours", "hrs");
        if(mFtime.contains("hour")){
            mFtime = mFtime.replace("hour", "hrs");
        }
    }

    /*PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
    String mConvertedtime = p.format(date);*/
    viewHolder.updatedDate.setText(mFtime);
    }
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    if (imageurl != null && !imageurl.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, viewHolder.imgflag);
            viewHolder.imgflag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        String uri = "@drawable/default_logo_list";

        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());

        Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        viewHolder.imgflag.setImageDrawable(res);
    }

    if (mCategoryName != null)
        viewHolder.cat_title.setText(mCategoryName);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    viewHolder.increaseText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

}
```

Comment: share your java code

Comment: Thanks Audumbar, I shared My java code

Comment: Sorry! We can't see your java code.

Comment: It's available below xml code.